# SQLite - Insert special symbols (trademark, ...) into table

Tags: sqlite, insert, special-characters, utf-16

How can I insert special symbols like trademark into SQLite table? I have tried to use PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-16" with no effect :(

Comment: Please post the query/code you are using for insertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved. it is necessary to open DB file with sqlite3_open16, then execute command PRAGMA encoding = \"UTF-16\"; (I am not sure, if it is necessary). Now the insert will be done with UTF-16.
To select from db (to get column value) is necessary to use sqlite3_column_text16 function

Answer (score 2):

Typically if you surround an SQL entry with ''Single quotes, it goes in as a literal.

i.e.

```
'™'
```

Comment: problem solved. it is necessary to open DB file with sqlite3_open16, then execute command PRAGMA encoding = \"UTF-16\"; (I am not sure, if it is necessary). Now the insert will be done with UTF-16.